Bean Classname not resolving after spring upgrade to 6.x
I have added a property file to the context which has this key rules.custom.rule
<bean id="myRule" class="${rules.custom:com.abc.MyRule}">
    <property name="config" ref="Config"/>
</bean>

I have following spring config and the class was always resolved form me after I upgrade the spring
I am getting this error

Cannot find class [${rules.custom:com.abc.MyRule}] for bean with name 'myRule' defined in class path resource

I am looking to initialize the bean myRule with an instance of com.abc.MyRule
